# What will happen if you lose the last 1 of your reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

If you see the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)>[Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you can see that [Creating Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) is one of the privileges earned at 1 rep. New users start with 1, so they can start questioning/answering right away. Right now I have 10 rep, a low value since I wasn't active for some time. Thus, it may be possible for me to lose all the reps, if I get too many down votes or something.

If that happens so, I think I may even lose the [Creating Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege, if my reputation falls to zero. It is almost impossible to do something here, unless I make a new account or I earn reps again by the question already uploaded.

Is this possible? I mean, is the first 1 reputation protected or not? If not, then what specifically will happen if I lose it?

Comment: You can't go below 1 reputation.

Comment: This is clearly explained in the [Reputation Section of the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, your reputation cannot drop below 1. That'd be a painful mistake for anyone who asked a bad question as their first.

You *can* get [question banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/359284) though, which means you will not be able to ask questions without improving your old ones.

Comment: Oh... Thanks... I was just worried if I may be banned from Stack Overflow by low rep.