# Is there any deficit reputation to be paid back?

Tags: support, reputation

I understand that a user's reputation can't be less than 1. At least a new entrant begins with 1. However, what happens if an old folk loses so much that he now has a 'deficit'?  Is there a system that monitors 'negative reputation' at the background and deducts the deficit when reputation appreciates?

Comment: Nope, you aren't affected by those downvotes (unfortunately, in many cases).

Comment: Yeah.  That is indeed an annoyance with 'member for today' bad questions.

Comment: Can someone explain how this is consistent with the fact that when a user is deleted everything they ever voted for is changed back? I assumed that this meant that reputation is meant to be an exact sum of all votes (and other things that give rep) someone has received, in which case there would be a deficit.

Comment: @Random832 If a user is deleted together with their votes, the reputation of affected users is recalculated as if those votes never existed.

Comment: the [linked question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286316/what-will-happen-if-you-lose-the-least-1-of-the-reputation) is marked as duplicate of this one, shouldn't be the other way around? Dup message: _This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer._

Comment: @Random832: SO is not a zero-sum game; there is not a finite quantity of reputation being moved around the system: it is generated and annihilated on demand. You accidentally answered your own question by observing that it is a deleted users' _votes_ that are undone, not the resulting change in reputation of the votant (although that is usually an inevitable indirect effect).

Comment: Just thinking logically about things, if there hypothetically was a deficit to be paid back, don't you think they'd have designed the system to show the actual amount (ex: -10) instead of just leaving it at 1?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You cannot go below 1. Ever.

There is no deficit either – you cannot lose reputation beyond one and nothing keeps score to deduct it later. We don't kick people when they are down nor do we save the kicks for when they get up again.

Comment: when you said "We don't kick people when they are down nor do we save the kicks for when they get up again", you just made the whole point appear so clear than a thousand lines might do. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleStrand, you know, I can understand why you are glad and how you feel about this answer.  It gives me the idea that "He that is down needs our compassion and not crucifixion". Those who designed this particular rule for SO were really thoughtful; and, I just can't stop pondering this answer also.

Comment: Does this mean if the account that downvoted you was deleted you get extra reputation for free? It seems like SE is definitely in the business of "saving kicks" in one case. (I only lost 10 rep to a recent account removal, but I was shocked by the existence of this feature having read this answer earlier today)

Comment: @Random832 no, that user had **upvoted** you. If they had 'kicked' you any reputation lost would have been returned instead. Account deletions remove all votes as if never cast.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're missing the point. The fact that it does anything _at all_ suggests that rep score is meant to be a total of _all_ past events. Why does that exclude ones that happened while your reputation happened to be 1?

Comment: @Random832: What have votes that *gave* you reputation and are now deleted have anything to do with your reputation being at 1? You could not have *been* at 1 rep since you gained those 10 points before. Otherwise they could not have been taken away now that the vote has been deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're missing the point. It's not about a direct connection between the two, it's about what they imply about the reputation system as a whole.

Comment: @Random832: A user account being deleted takes with it all the votes cast. Your reputation is then recalculated as if those votes never took place. If you gained reputation from those votes, you lose that reputation. If you *lost* reputation, you regain it. Etc. This has nothing to do with the minimum being 1; that still stands and is recalculated with the remaining votes being re-applied taking all caps into account. This also works with the *upper* daily reputation cap, for example.

Comment: If someone's reputation was 1, then they got 5 downvotes (reputation is still 1), then those accounts got deleted, does their reputation go up? If not, then it _did_ save the "kicks".

Comment: @Random832: what it says about the reputation system is that only votes from accounts that remain on the site ever count. There are exceptions made for accounts with a long history, good standing and a lot of votes, but those are extremely rare and meant to lessen the impact of removing an account that was obviously a significant part of the site.

Comment: @Random832: why would reputation go up because accounts get deleted? Those downvotes never cost reputation *in the first place*.

Comment: @Random832: I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding why you lost reputation through the deleted account. You were not downvoted. You were **upvoted**. That vote is now simply gone.

Comment: How does the algorithm know whether those votes were ineffective due to a cap or not?

Comment: @Random832: because the effect of each vote is recorded and all votes are re-calculated when votes are deleted.

Comment: And once again YOU ARE MISSING THE POINT. Why doesn't the effect of each vote _also_ get recalculated, so that a vote that didn't cost any reputation at the time (because reputation was 1) can cost reputation now (because reputation no longer was 1 because a different downvote was removed)?

Comment: @Random832: Please stop shouting and step back a little. There is no consistency here. You are misunderstanding what I am saying. Of course wether a vote hits the cap or not is also recalculated, that is what I am saying.

Comment: "Of course wether a vote hits the cap or not is also recalculated" - so if you get two downvotes, but only one has an effect, then you will be _denied_ the rep increase from that account being deleted because the other one is waiting in the wings, which directly contradicts "nor do we save the kicks for when they get up again."

Comment: @Random832: no, one kick was removed, as if it never happened. So you suddenly want the other downvote to no longer count? It did at the time! Account deletions for reasons other than moderation (e.g. removing fraudulent accounts) is rare, in any case, so those votes removed **should not have been cast in the first place**.

Comment: No, the point is that it _didn't_ count at the time, because the cap was already hit due to the first (now-deleted) one. Making it suddenly count now isn't _wrong_, but it does contradict the principle you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @Random832: I understand why you think it shouldn't apply. But the deleted vote no longer exists. The whole system is built around the fact that only existing votes count. A deleted vote is a vote that was never cast.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't change the fact that the vote that _wasn't_ deleted, did not have an effect at the time it was cast, but is being given an effect now. In other words, it's a "kick" that is being "saved".

Comment: @Random832: I disagree on that point. I think I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Random832: You misunderstood the answer. The kicks not being saved are kicks on the one-rep user, not kicks that the one-rep user may have cast on others via downvoting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You misunderstood my question. I am talking about "kicks" _on_ the one-rep user _by_ a different user that is subsequently deleted (or by a third user who downvoted them after their rep was 1 but before the second user was deleted). And really my point is that the two features seem to come from a very different philosophy on how reputation should work, whether it is stateless or stateful.

Comment: I prefer my math associative and commutative.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the conversation so far, @LightnessRacesinOrbit is saying that, with the current system, `1+5-2-2-2-2+5=6`, and if two of those downvotes are removed due to a deleted account, you get `1+5-2-2+5=7`. @Random832 on the other hand is saying that when two downvotes are removed from `1+5-2-2-2-2+5=6`, you should get `1+5-2-2-2-2+5+4=10` instead. Right? Or was it more along the lines of `1+5-2-2-1-0+5=6` becomes `1+5-1-0+5=10`? Honestly, I don't see a problem with either approach, though I think @Lightness's explanation of "it's like the votes never existed" makes sense.

Comment: @KyleStrand My point was that there are users that post total complete crap, over and over again. My statement was simply that they probably deserve a bit worse than we are giving them (though of course, a question-ban is usually forthcoming for such users.) In general I have no problem whatsoever with this policy/strategy

Comment: @Random832: in any case, AFAIK it goes both ways, so if you hit the rep cap (200) a day and one of those upvotes gets deleted, another one takes its place (I'd say it's not saved for later, it just has the effect it didn't at the time).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I know what you meant, hence the almost-upvote.

Comment: @Random832 The closest to a "saved kick" that could come from a scenario involving a deleted user would be the following: (1) UserA upvotes one of UserB's posts. (2) One of UserB's posts is downvoted to oblivion, leaving UserB at 1 rep. (3) UserA deletes their account. (UserB's rep does not change, because rep can't go below 1.) (4) UserB gets some more upvotes.

Comment: Now, the question is, was there a "saved kick" in the form of a rep loss due to UserA's account deletion? I.e., if UserA's initial upvote was worth 5 points (i.e. it was for a question), and UserB then gets an upvote on an answer (5 points), will UserB end up with 11 rep (no "saved kick") or 6 rep (the "kick" of the user-deletion was "saved")? My guess is that even in this case, UserB's rep is will be 11, not 6, meaning that there are *no* "kicks" that are "saved" until a user has enough rep for them to count.  @MartijnPieters (or anyone else who knows), can you confirm or deny this?

Comment: @KyleStrand: just remove the votes from the deleted account and replay the remaining votes in order, following the same rule that any vote that brings you past a limit (200 up in a day, or not lower than 1) is truncated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, guess confirmed?

Comment: Delete the vote that the account made and replay the votes in the order they occurred.  Nothing could be more clear and succinct.   Thank you @MartijnPieters

Comment: Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation - notice the lack of  "+1", "-10" etc events.  Rep changes that are undone *never happened* as far as your rep score is concerned -- if they instead "did an opposite event", they would be recorded in that log.  The pretty UI version of your rep does show you the "-10" on the current day, but that is a "lie we tell to children" to make the UI prettier.