# New users: Unfair rep changes depending the order of Downvotes and Upvotes in same Question or Answer

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

I've thinking about this a while. And I think is a bug. The sorting of the votes IN ONE SINGLE POST will give you different reputation...

SCENARIO: user with 1 rep ask bad question. This user gets 3 downvotes and 1 upvote.

- User get 3 downvotes and after a upvote.

  > FINAL USER REP = 6
- User get 1 upvote and after 3 downvotes

  > FINAL USER REP = 1
- User get 2 downvotes 1 upvote and 1 downvote

  > FINAL USER REP = 3

Isn't this unfair?

**PS:** I don't refer to [Is there any deficit reputation to be paid back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288629/is-there-any-deficit-reputation-to-be-paid-back/288630#288630) I'm refering to rep changes in *SAME QUESTION OR ANSWER*.

**PSS:** Either refer to edited / improved / modified questions.

Comment: consider [edit]ing to add a reference to [Is there any deficit reputation to be paid back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288630/839601) to help readers see why downvotes can't push reputation under 1

Comment: not the same, i'm refering to SAME QUESTION, not about punishing someone by a bad question or answer in the past.

Comment: I mean that answer over there explains why rep "cannot go below 1. Ever"

Comment: Again is not same... I'm saying is not fair diferent reputation with same down and upvotes.... I edited my question to clarify ;)

Comment: That's a feature. New user posts a bad question with 1 rep, gets 8 downvotes. They subsequently edit the question into shape, and get 4 upvotes as a result. Net reputation afterwards: 20. Happy user: check. User getting the message about improving your question when downvoted: check.

Comment: So you're proposing rep be able to become negative.  SE has made it clear that they don't want to do that.  The current behavior is the intended behavior.

Comment: NOPE! **I'm proposing the final rep changes of one single question or answer must be same in all cases.**

Comment: @JordiCastilla: but it cannot be. There are other places where the order matters too, with the reputation cap. *Not* honouring the order would be *unfair* because a user that fixes their content for the better would be hurt more than a user that vandalises their content.

Comment: so, the user can ask a friend after 20 downvotes for an upvote and get positive rep??? **UNFAIR x 1000** LIFO and FIFO are not for this case...

Comment: @JordiCastilla Well, that would be voting fraud, and is a problem even for users not at 1 rep.  That said, your assertion that someone getting an upvote after 20 downvotes on one rep should still be at 1 rep is you proposing rep be negative.  As I've said, SE has gone out of their way to *prevent* rep from going negative.  They don't want to support it.

Comment: Why would it be desirable for them *not* to get the benefit of UVs *after* they edit/fix a bad Q?

Comment: @JordiCastilla keep in mind that after 20 downvotes, the question is almost certainly deleted.  Either by the system or by enough flags.

Comment: @Plutonix That's not really what's going on here though.  The real question is why the user isn't paying the price for the downvotes they got before the upvote(s), not why they should get a benefit for upvotes they attract.  Why shouldn't the user face consequences for posting a bad question in the first place?

Comment: @Servy: so the possibility that they can improve and learn is not strong enough a reason for the current mechanics to stay? If the user produces actual bad content, they'll do so consistently and get banned soon enough.

Comment: Did you know if you gained 195 rep today, and get a downvote on an answer and then an upvote you will have 200 rep, while if you get an upvote first and then a down vote you have 199 rep?!  Remove the rep cap! Totally unfair! (maybe it is, but it really doesn't matter in the long run).

Comment: Who cares about this? Anyone halfway serious about participating on SO will have surpassed single-digit reputation in very short time. And from then on it won't really matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually applying some consequences to the votes isn't preventing them from improving and learning.  That's a false dichotomy.  If the user is the type of person to realize their mistake, learn, and improve, they're likely to do so whether or not they end up at 10 or 1 rep after asking their question.

Comment: @Servy: but there are plenty of people that are insecure enough and apprehensive enough that applying down-votes 'after the fact' as it were *does* have an impact. I rather err on that side of caution.

Comment: Related from MSE: [Downvoting 1 rep user has no effect, but re-casting does if the user meanwhile earned some rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174113/downvoting-1-rep-user-has-no-effect-but-re-casting-does-if-the-user-meanwhile-e/174136#174136)

Comment: I just upvoted a question that has 2 downvotes. Op made no edit in between, it's just different people having different ideas of what a good question is. I agree, they should be on 6 just cause I voted last. If the justification is that OP are being rewarded after an edit, then maybe a check should be in place to see if OP made an edit. In this example, someone else has edited the title so I don't know if there is already a check, but the content hasn't changed so it definitely has been approved or otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Lets take the following two scenarios:

- New user *Foo* adds a badly formatted question and forgets to include the error message. They receive 2 down-votes in quick succession, and a comment asking for the error.

  *Foo* realises their mistake and add in the error message and clean up some other errors in the post. They now receive 1 up-vote since now they have a decent question.

  Their final reputation score: +6.
- New user *Bar* adds a reasonable question, not too great, but they used some funny language and put the post on twitter. Someone bites and up-votes the post once. A commenter points out a minor mistake.

  *Bar* is actually also quite drunk, and takes offence to the commenter. They *replace* the content of their post with something almost the same but actually quite rude. Not offensive enough to be flagged into oblivion, but they did something stupid to it.

  The post gets voted down 2 times for this action since now it is no longer a useful question.

  Final reputation score: +1.

Users *Foo* and *Bar* both got the same number of up and downvotes for their question. But the *order matters*; questions are not always static. Do you feel that *Bar* deserved to get the same number of points as *Foo* here?

*Foo* will have received the message that improving content is good. Once *Bar* sobers up, they'll hopefully have learned that defacing your content will cost you reputation points.

And in the end, if either user continues to contribute positively, the difference of 5 points at the start **won't make any difference in the long run**.

Comment: You realize that the *far* more likely scenario for the first case is  someone posts a bad question, gets downvotes, and then people who simply dislike the fact that SO has strict quality standards, don't even know that SO has strict quality standards, or just don't care and have the same problem, upvotes the terrible question.   The frequency of questions that get to a score of -4 have an *extremely* low probability of being improved, and a fairly reasonable probability of attracting some number of upvotes despite its quality.

Comment: @Servy: as someone who downvotes bad content all day long, this isn't actually all that common, not in the tags that I frequent anyway. I do have *WTF* moments when I see an upvote on a post I strongly feel should be downvoted into oblivion, yes, but they are not *so* frequent I see a problem. there. Would it be more palatable if I reduced the number of downvotes received to 2? The outcome would be the same here.

Comment: So questions that get a *lot* of downvote (as in, say 6 or more) often don't get upvotes at all.  When they *do* get upvotes after some time, in my experiences, it is rarely after comprehensive edits to the question that improve it.  Of the upvotes to highly downvoted posts, most haven't improved significantly in quality, in my experiences.  That's for questions though; answers I see a lot more people post wrong answers and then fix them, with votes to reflect those changes.

Comment: I don't think that that's really that much of a problem. Heavily downvoted questions are almost always also (going to be) closed, and the roomba takes care of deletion within 9 days for those.

Comment: [The moral of the story is that with a contrived example, you can prove anything.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html)

Comment: @resueman: you are welcome to come up with better examples. The *intent* here doesn't change though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is unfair, but life isn't fair.  And in my opinion, this current system is actually fair.  Consider how those voting patterns you mentioned may pan out:

- User get 3 downvotes and after a upvote:  This upvote at the end might be because of a clarifying edit.  And we want to reward good improvements to any post.
- User get 1 upvote and after 3 downvotes:  Think of an answer that initially looks good, and then someone points out a huge problem.  One upvote for the initial "that should work" and 3 downvotes for others realizing that answer is wrong and unhelpful.
- User get 2 downvotes 1 upvote and 1 downvote.  This is just weird timing/luck.  I don't really have an explanation for this.

The bottom line is that, generally speaking, the most current votes reflect the most current state of the post.  So preventing the rep loss for improving a question and enforcing the rep loss when the post is revealed to be bad is a feature.

Comment: This is a nice answer when you refer to questions with edits, but my question appeared with an unmodified question

Comment: And that doesn't take into account events outside of downvotes:  User gets 3 downvotes, then an upvote, but also gets 5 close votes, and people who closed it come back 2 days later and delete it.  FINAL USER REP = 1.  Ta da!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables This is a unproductive comment, if you want to discuss please read my question and the answers, anybody said nothing about edits, flaggings or closing votes... if you wanna be funny buy a friend

Comment: @JordiCastilla - the point is, even if someone gets an upvote after a downvote, there are mechanisms in place to make sure that they don't get to keep any unfairly earned rep.  You're not looking at the bigger picture of how all the pieces and parts of the site interact.

Comment: Unfair rep changes is exactly what is happening in the case I exposed...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ok so you are pointing out that deleted posts also revert any rep changes (fair or unfair)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu - that is correct.  And trust me, people who vote to close, and see the question getting unwarranted upvotes, *will* go back and delete the question.

Comment: deleted posts when? if you delete a post you revert the rep instead a long time passed...

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes, and so if the user started at 1 rep, they'll go back to 1 rep.