# Should low rep users be able to delete their own questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, new-users

Recently I've spent time helping new users, taking time to understand their question, work on solutions and respond and so have many other users. Only for the question to just get deleted without any resolution.

Sometimes I've gone away from the page to work on a question in an IDE, come back with an answer ready and the owner has deleted it. Very frustrating.

Most recent one was this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297311/cant-peek-from-an-empty-stack-error-java

The question has a positive score, a couple of close votes, but the user presumably solved their problem and just deleted it without telling anyone the solution.

New users may not understand that questions aren't to be deleted once they have a solution, they are for others to learn from too.

Comment: Rescuing a question with a *lot* of comments and downvoted wild guesses as answers is a tall order.  The OP usually falls on his sword when he discovers the very mundane reason, like a threading race.  Banging the question into shape to make it obvious that this is the correct answer isn't usually worth it.  The very basic thing that went wrong here was a serious lack of repro code.   Had the OP worked on it, he probably would never have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree it may not be recoverable, like in the example I gave. But I think a new user should learn from having their question closed in that case. They could learn from the close reason. I don't think they learn from self-deleting and would be more likely to post low quality again.

Comment: Well, teaching them to delete poor questions is arguably more important.  Getting rid of such questions is otherwise a rather major effort that usually requires the participation of 8 other users.  You can always flag a moderator when you think the Q+A didn't have enough time to gather upvotes so the OP can't delete it anymore.

Comment: Most questions are not deletable anyway, because by the time it's flagged as a duplicate, off topic, or a bad question, it will already have received answers.

Comment: Perhaps this comment from the OP underlies the delettion? "Starting to wonder if it's a problem somewhere else in the program, which will make it harder to find". If this proved to be the case the question is indeed useless.

Comment: While I certainly can empathize with the "I-made-a-solution-but-the-question-was-deleted" situation, I must admit I've always tended to favor the idea of an individual having the ability to delete their own posts. I think decisions in this vein must, to the extent possible, favor the right of someone to decide *not* to say something.

Comment: You can always write a comment to the user asking whether he's looking for an answer like the one you're about to spend a lot of time writing. That can help encourage him to focus the question so it's actually worth answering, as well as getting a sense of whether he's likely to wait for your answer or just delete in shame, so you don't waste your time as often. (The down side is someone else might see your comment and decide to "steal" your rep by slapping together a mediocre answer that just pads out the comment, but that's a less annoying problem; you can still post your better answer.)

Comment: @DavidW If a user deletes a question you've contributed an answer on, flag for moderator attention. The purpose of the site is not for someone to run aways and hoard the answer, but have the answer (and the question) shared. A mod will restore the question (bringing your answer with it) and give you an upvote to stop the user deleting the question again :-) I don't know if the user is also contacted...

Comment: Good info, @BillWoodger. Thank you for that information. I was not aware of it.

Comment: @DavidW You can flag one of your posts with a custom flag, include the link to your deleted answer (since us lowly ones can't see the deleted question and may not know the user) and an explanation and one of the mods will be happy to oblige. I'd have lost this one otherwise, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28439327/1927206, which I was unimpressed about when the OP took their question away shortly after I'd posted it.

Comment: Also if you have a good answer to a deleted question, you could make a new question that explains the same problem and add your answer onto it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> Should low rep users be able to delete their own questions?

Yes.

The situation you describe is frustrating, but there's a lot to be said in favour of allowing folks to delete their content when they come to realize it is somehow bad. It would be cruel not to.

You already can't delete your question if it has received an answer with at least one upvote.

To me, that's always seemed like a good compromise between the interests of the asker and those of the answerer(s).

Comment: "You already can't delete your question if it has received an answer with at least one upvote." Did not know that. That is a good compromise.

Comment: Poor OP's - sometimes they realize they have asked a poor question and they get downvote after downvote until it appears to them they can never recover to a level of votes where they can even comment!  That's how I felt in the beginning, and it's discouraging.

Comment: @BGM: I think it helps that [you can't go below 1 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288630/1340389).

Comment: Really?  I didn't realize that.  Over on Puzzles SE I posted a question and I know it's been downvoted at least 15 times, and upvoted as many (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/look-up-the-panda-bear) and at one point it was even at -6!  It was one of my first posts there and I was really dismayed and thought I'd never recover without deleting the question.  But it is a beta site, and in the spirit of beta I suffered the chaos...  (act of humility)

Comment: +1 for `It would be cruel not to.` Alot of VLQ questions I have seen are often first-timers - not allowing them to delete would deprive them of what can often be an appropriate action.

Comment: I'm very reluctant to take away the asker's right to delete their own question under any circumstances. An answerer stands to lose a few points, which is annoying, but the asker potentially stands to lose much more, since we do not know anything about their circumstances we should make assumptions. Don't deleted questions stay in the system and remain visible to the asker?

Comment: @TimLong unfortunately, there is a lot of abuse around the possibility of deleting your own question - that's why the limitations were created in the first place. Some people who will selfishly delete their question and the resulting answers once *they* have an answer, subverting SO's goal of providing answers to future generations - one of the main reasons to contribute answers for many people. If there's a really pressing circumstance, you can flag for moderator attention and explain why your question needs to be taken down.

Comment: I recently experienced a question being deleted right after I answered it. The question was legit and had not been downvoted. I suspect it was about homework and that the asker wanted to use my answer and delete the evidence. Something should be done to prevent such abuse of the SO site and its contributors.

Answer (score 24):

I can understand why this can be frustrating; I've been hit by it a couple of times.

I think the best approach is to be less quick on the uptake to answer. This is one of those situations (and there are several) when going off to formulate an answer is *not* necessarily worthwhile. If you can train yourself to better spot this sort of thing (for example, noting that the question was quite poor with no minimal testcase) and avoid answering when you do, you won't have any problem.

We don't want to encourage such questions to be posted, anyway.

Comment: You're right. `We don't want to encourage such questions to be posted, anyway.`

Answer (score 13):

A counter argument is all the times that you bump into new user questions in the close vote queue, where the most helpful thing the person could do is delete it.

Since close-vote-reviewers can't delete, but they can suggest self-deletion, it would be a shame to have this taken away.

I'm not in a position to determine which is more of a hassle, I'm just putting this reason why I personally appreciate new users being able to delete their questions: so I can advise them to do so, and save the close vote queue some unnecessary work.

Comment: OK good points. Do you think positive score on the question should be a factor in determining self deletion? i.e. only a negative score could be self deleted.

Comment: I totally agree with that idea @weston .   There are reasons why positive voted questions need to be closed anyhow, but I can't think of a case where a new user would be persuaded to do it themselves.    So your idea holds water.

Comment: It turns out this is _almost_ the situation anyhow, eh?   You can't delete a question with an _answer_ with upvotes.    I think that this rule doesn't save you from the sad case where you put effort into answering what was a poor question with close votes, because it's less likely that a) anyone else would have answered and b) that answer got upvoted.    But hopefully in the long run this is a corner case - more often than not answering poor questions encourages poor questions.

Comment: This could also be achieved by giving the possibility to vote for "flag moderator for deletion" such that the final decision to delete is made by a moderator and not a - presumably - newbie. Unfortunately, allowing low rep users to delete their own questions opens up for abuse of the site.

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that the answer you gave would be valuable to other programmers with a similar question, you could always reword the question and repost it with your self-answer.

Answer (score 4):

i'm a new user and i've already deleted my own question without posting solutions ...
why ? because i sometimes find that my question was duplicated or just a typo error ... And really the aswer coundn't be usefull for others ...
but i do understand that this can be frustrating for people trying to help me ...
i think SO should create rule like :

1. You can't delete your question if someone voteup it (atleast someone is interested by answer)
   OR
2. You can't delete your question before 12 hours AND
3. confirmation message before delete like "If you delete this question because you found a solution by yourself you should rather post if for help community"

Somethings like that ...

First post on meta , was feeling concern by your question ...

Sry for this english ... regards

Comment: I agree. I have deleted a couple questions of mine. Recently, I deleted one after 20+ hours because I realize the _actual_ root of the issue. I _was_ able to reopen it, after which I completely edited it to express my new concern. > > I think the confirmation should ask the user to post their solution. If they submit it was a typo or a solution after restarting, then they should be able to close.

Comment: Upvotes seem like a red herring to me. The inalienable rights of the asker should never be trumped by the opinion of others, no matter how bad an idea it seems. No-one should be forced to have their content displayed online if they don't want to.